# How to show all the annotations in Hichcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Is there any possible way to show all the annotations i have provided to the high charts?

I found that some annotations that lie far away from the plot area are not rendered.

I only have annotations that are parallel to the x-axis.

If my plot lies from 0-100 in the y-axis and if I have an annotation at 200. The annotation does not show.

I have been looking at the docs but can't find any config that might work. Maybe I missed something.

I just need the config to make it work so I haven't posted any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not currently possible in HighCharts.

I used to draw another plot in the chart which is in white color (add the color same as your background). The line would extend from the first annotation to the last annotation.

```
proxyData=[
      [
        distance,
        maxAnnotationHeight
      ],
      [ 
        distance,
        minAnnotationHeight
      ]
    ];
```

So a line is created but it is not seen because it is same as the background color.

```
   series: [
            {
              color: '#fff',
              data: proxyData
            },
            {
              name: 'Distance.',
              color: '#3073ea',
              lineWidth: 3,
              data: [...distanceData]
            }
          ]
```

I know it is a very hackish solution but this may be the only one available right now.